# Matplotlib heatmap failure

Tags: matplotlib, heatmap

This simple code is supposed to produce a smooth heatmap:

```
X = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
plt.imshow(X)
plt.show()
```

but what I got was these color blocks:

[image]

I tested it both in pycharm and jupyter and it was all the same. 
I am using python 3.5, installed matplotlib using pip.
Somebody please help.

Answer (score 0):

`imshow` can produce heatmaps with several different interpolation methods. The default appears to be `None`, so you get the "blocks" you see above. A different method, such as `bilinear`, will perform a smooth interpolation. Many other options are available. See [here](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/interpolation_methods.html) for a good overview of the different methods.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)

X = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
ax1.imshow(X, interpolation='None')
ax2.imshow(X, interpolation='bilinear')

ax1.set_title('None')
ax2.set_title('bilinear')

plt.show()
```

[image]